# Blazor bind html to textarea

Tags: html, textarea, bind, blazor

This seems simple but I haven't been able to find an answer. In my Blazor Server side program I have a popup email form that I pre-populate with text and the user can then edit it and click send for the program to send the email. If the user enters line breaks in the textarea they come back as \n and that is fine. However I have been unable to send text to the textarea with line breaks.

In the popup form I have:

```
        <div class="form-group-sm">
            <label class="control-label">Message</label>
            <textarea rows="4" @bind="EmailMessage" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
```

If I send

```
EmailMessage = "Test Email text \\nline two <br /> line 3";
```

I get
[image]

If I send

```
EmailMessage = Markdown.ToHtml("Test Email text \\nline two <br /> line 3");
```

I get
[image]

Is it possible to send line breaks to a textarea bound to a property that the user then can edit and send the text back to the program?

Ideally this would be for any html markup but for now I'll settle for line breaks.

Comment: Why do you escape \ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basic...you can augment it in many ways:

```
@page "/"

<div class="form-group-sm">
    <label class="control-label">Message</label>
    <textarea rows="4" value="@EmailMessage" @onchange="@((args) => EmailMessage = args.Value.ToString())" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>

<button @onclick="@(()=>{})">Refresh</button>



@code {
    private string emailMessage = "Test Email text \r\nline two \r\n line 3";
    
    public string EmailMessage
    {
        get =>  emailMessage;
        set
        {
            if (emailMessage != value)
            {
                emailMessage = ((MarkupString)value).ToString();
            }
        }

    }
 
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a bound solution and on the surface this is not. However, digging into it essentially it is doing what Blazor does underneath the binding and most of all it works. Thx!  [ASP.NET Core Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1)