# How can I submit an input or textarea with HTML tags in .NET Blazor server side approach?

Tags: c#, html, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

How can I submit an input of text type or a textarea which has **HTML** tags using **.NET Blazor server-side** approach?

When I submit an input of text type without **HTML** tags, the information submitted enters perfectly, but when I include some **HTML** tags in the input, the submitted text comes empty, how can I submit inputs with **HTML** tags?

Here is my **HTML** code:

```
<input type="text"
id="quill-result-body"
class="form-control"
required
@bind="BlogPost!.Body" />
```

As I mentioned, if the input does not have **HTML** tags, the submitted information located in BlogPost.Body comes perfect, but when I put some **HTML** tags, it comes empty.

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: "if the input does not have HTML tags".  What does this look like?  Is this a static server side rendered page or a true Blazor page within a Blazor application?

Comment: That's very interesting, I am using older Blazor version but it seems to handing it perfectly with CKEditor, InputTextArea and EditForm. I suggest you checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125393/blazor-bind-html-to-textarea

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis No sir, its about a HTML input that have inside HTML tags, not only text

Comment: @cycaHuH I have read that post but no solution with my problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: @MatiasNovillo - can you show more code - specifically  "its about a HTML input that have inside HTML tags, not only text".  Net version?, render mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code of new page that works for me - just created new Blazor Server to try.

```
@page "/html"

<h3>Test HTML Page</h3>

<EditForm Model="@EditModel" OnValidSubmit="SubmitForm">
    <input type="text"
           id="quill-result-body"
           class="form-control"
           required
           @bind="EditModel!.Body" />

    <div>@EditModel.Body</div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" value="Submit"/>
</EditForm>

@code {
    class BlogPost
    {
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    private BlogPost EditModel { get; set; } = new();

    private void SubmitForm()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(EditModel.Body);
    }
}
```

And here's HTML input and Console output.

[image: HTML Input][image: Console Output]

What Blazor .NET version do you use?

Comment: Cool, Im going to test your answer ASAP. And Im using .NET 8

Comment: Sir, it works, but, to comment, I can do it with the form tag, not estrictly with EditForm tag. Thanks!!!!